# In Angular dart, can a @Directive attribute take an anonymous function as value?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

In a decorator, I can use,

```dart
Decorator {
@NgCallback('attr')
  Function callback
```

to bind a callback function to a decorator. In the HTML template it is used like this:

```dart
<input attr="cmp.a_method()" />
```

The above function must though be available on the Component.

What I want to do, is bind an arbitrary anonymous function from the HTML template, something like this:

```dart
 <tag attr="(o1,o2) => //Dart code" />
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I've tried a few ways and am unable to do so. I even thought I was clever and added a simple functionReturn method to controller that took a function as an argument and returned it right away but doesn't get past the compile stage. Angular is unhappy with any syntax I put in there.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I fell back to a method on the component instead.